# Make Node.js server to WebRTC peer and send video from USB camera to client browser

Tags: node.js, video, stream, webrtc, peer

.
Hello

I have searched everywhere but still could not find any clear answer or example.

I have Raspberry Pi running as Node.js server with USB camera connected to it. I want to get video from that camera and send it to Node server client (browser) using webRTC. This would only be localhost and just one client.

I know that webRTC is meant to be browser to browser thing and server is only used for signaling. But this must be possible. I have just started with Node.js and can`t figure this out myself.

Somebody must have done it by now...webRTC is getting very popular. I have seen similar questions dating back to 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same idea in past. I have 2 guinea pigs and wanted to have a live video from my home to check what is going on with them when I'm at work.

I have Raspberry Pi and a camera for it, so I tried to do something similar.

And at the end I finished with this article https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera,

It tells how to get Raspberry Pi with camera, install Janus WebRTC Gateway and then stream video into public. Hope it will help you or at least direct to to right solution